# Proving First Difference is more efficient than OLS

Tags: time-series, least-squares, fixed-effects-model, efficiency

I am trying to prove that the First Difference method is asymptotically more efficient than OLS when the error term follows a random walk. Assume the following model

$$\begin{align}y_i&= \mathbf{X}_i\beta+\varepsilon_i\end{align}$$
where $y_i,\varepsilon_i\in\mathbb{R}^T,\ \beta\in\mathbb{R}^K$ and $\mathbf{X}_i\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times k}$

The first difference estimator is obtained by pre-multiplying this system of equations with
$$\underset{\mathbb{R}^{(T-1)\times T}}{\mathbf{Q}_T}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &\cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & &\ddots & \ddots & & 0\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Assume
(i) $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i|\mathbf{X}_i]=0$ (ii) $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Q}_T\varepsilon_i\varepsilon_i^T\mathbf{Q}_T^T|\mathbf{X}_i]=\sigma^2_\Delta\mathbf{I}_{T-1}$.

Then the variance of the original error term is not identified because $\mathbf{Q}_T$ is not invertible. My first way to conitnue was to use the generalised inverse, so that
$\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i\varepsilon_i^T|\mathbf{X}_i]=(\mathbf{Q}_T^T\mathbf{Q}_T)^g$, then

\begin{align}
&N\cdot Avar(\hat{\beta}_{OLS}|\mathbf{X}_i)=(\mathbf{X}_i^T\mathbf{X}_i)^{-1}(\mathbf{X}_i(\mathbf{Q}_T^T\mathbf{Q}_T)^g\mathbf{X}_i)(\mathbf{X}_i^T\mathbf{X}_i)^{-1}\\\
&N\cdot Avar(\beta_{FD}|\mathbf{X}_i)=(\mathbf{X}_i^T\mathbf{Q}_T^T\mathbf{Q}_T\mathbf{X}_i)^{-1}
\end{align}
For $$N\cdot Avar(\hat{\beta}_{OLS}|\mathbf{X}_i) - N\cdot Avar(\hat{\beta}_{FD}|\mathbf{X}_i)$$ to be positive semi-definite,

$$N\cdot Avar(\hat{\beta}_{FD}|\mathbf{X}_i)^{-1} - N\cdot Avar(\hat{\beta}_{OLS}|\mathbf{X}_i)^{-1}$$
must be too.
Then, after some algebra
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X}_i^T(\mathbf{Q}_T^T\mathbf{Q}_T-\mathbf{X}_i(\mathbf{X}_i^T(\mathbf{Q}_T^T\mathbf{Q}_T)^g\mathbf{X}_i)^{-1}\mathbf{X}_i^T)\mathbf{X}_i
\end{equation}
meaning that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q}_T^T\mathbf{Q}_T-\mathbf{X}_i(\mathbf{X}_i^T(\mathbf{Q}_T^T\mathbf{Q}_T)^g\mathbf{X}_i)^{-1}\mathbf{X}_i^T\end{equation}
must be PSD. But this is where I am stuck, since I cannot do anything with the generalised inverse (apart from decomposing it to, say, $\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{C}$). Could anyone give me a hint or how to continue (or give a hint for an alternative proof?)